# NSInternalInconsistencyException iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, exception, crashlytics

I got a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` crash from appStore app via crashalytics.

> class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.

But I used `AVPlayerItem` on 3-4 ViewControllers. So I don't know on which ViewController it caused a crash.

Please help me to found it out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the platform myself, but can't you just add exception handling on the 4 mentioned locations and either handle the error or add additional information to the exception?

Comment: If you have a symbolicated crash log, you’ll see which of your methods caused the object to be deallocated (further down in the stack trace). Maybe start investigating there.